# Pronunciation of "солнце"

Tags: произношение

Why isn't the consonant л pronounced in "солнце" ( it is pronounced ['sont͡sə]] instead of [ˈsolnt͡sə] ) ? Is that a result of a pronunciation rule or is it an exception?

Comment: В словах Гольфстрим и ангстрем произносятся все пять подряд идущих согласных.

Comment: I think that this question while technically being on-topic is of a very poor quality - so I've down-voted it.

Comment: @shabunc Sorry, but I do not understand why this question is of a poor quality. I could not find the answer of it based on the Russian pronunciation rules I found so far on the Internet. I am sure other Russian students will ask themselves the same question. Also, if the answer is simple, it is a pity you took your time to criticize instead of quickly providing a short answer.

Comment: Asking why something is not pronounced is a strange thing to do - why k is not pronounced in knowledge? Because at some period in time k was omitted.

Comment: "k" is not pronounced in "know" because most English letters can be pronounced in many distinct ways and there are no rules to decide how to choose the correct pronunciation (or at least there are so many exceptions that the rules are not worth learning). The pronunciation of each word must be learned by heart. That is not the case with several other languages with more regular spelling, such as German, Spanish and Russian. In those, usually a student learns the pronunciation rules and the few exceptions to them. I just need to know whether this word is an exception of the pronunciation rules.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista ah, I see, I've revoked my downvote and will try to answer.

Comment: It wouldn't be "wrong" for you to pronounce the word the way you would naturally think it should be pronounced. It's just that a sequence of many consonants is harder to pronounce, so you'd naturally find yourself dropping the л. Try saying it out loud a few times, with a proper Russian л, you'll see for yourself.

Comment: @Galastel I guess that "hard" is subjective. There are other consonants clusters which could be seen as equally hard to pronounce and no letters are dropped when pronouncing them. Also, I see no reason why л is dropped instead of  н.  IMHO it is more productive to avoid trying to find any logic in the pronunciation of this consonant cluster and just memorize it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only words in Russian ending by `олнц` are derivatives from "солнце". In all the rest of the words with `олн` + vowel `л` is alway pronounced. I'm aware only of two words with `олн` + consonant, that are:

- [чолнт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%82) - л is pronounced in this word.
- [Солнзас](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF) (or Солнзап) - it's a river and as far as I know `л` is pronounced there.

So yes, that's an exception. But, strictly speaking, statement "in all Russian words with 'олнц' `л` is always omitted" will be valid.

As a side-note - there are quite a lot of words where one should memorize the Russian pronunciation - in `сердце` `д` is mute, in `грустно` `т` is mute, in `здравствуй` first `в` is mute. I can go on for a while - it's not as crazy as in English - but still. Here's [a link](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5/) that might be useful for you.

Comment: The commonality between all those words where a consonant is "swallowed" is that it's in a sequence of three consonants (making it harder to pronounce). *Which* consonant in the sequence gets silenced is about ease of pronunciation. Take the sequence дц in сердце: unless you put a very deliberate stop between those two letters, the first bleeds into the second.

Answer (score 1):

л is not omitted from солнце by everyone. Most do omit it, some do not. Both is correct.

Comment: Thanks for that information! Is the pronunciation of л in this consonant cluster related to a specific region or is it random in the entire Russia?